# openGL textures beginner question - 1D Texture creation?

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

**EDIT**

Ok I added some changes to my texture rendering, and I'm now at a point that it doesn't look how I want it but before I try to change anything I just want to be sure I'm on the right path. The problem I'm trying to fix is: I have 180000 vertices. Each of them can be from one of 190 "classes". Each class can have a different color assigned at a different time. So I'm trying to create a texture with 190 colors, and for each of the 180000 vertexes have a textureCoord to the coresponding class. So for some code:

```
    self.bufferTextureIndex = glGenBuffersARB(1)
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferTextureIndex)
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, ADT.arrayByteCount(textureIndexes), ADT.voidDataPointer(textureIndexes), GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB)               

    self.texture = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, self.texture)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGB, 190, 0, GL_RGB , GL_FLOAT, textureArray)
```

So textureIndexes is an array of floats from [0..1]. len(textureIndexes) is the number of vertices I'm using (180000). For  the texture, textureArray contains 190 * 3 floats coresponding to the RBG of the colors I want for each class.

The drawing part:

```
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferTextureIndex)
    glTexCoordPointer(1, GL_FLOAT, 0, None);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, self.texture)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D)       
    if type == GL_POINTS:
        glDrawArrays( GL_POINTS, 0, len(self.vertices) / 3 ); 
    else: 
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(self.triangles) , GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, ADT.voidDataPointer(self.triangles))
```

So does this approach seem right ? The result isn't what I'm expecting but that might be for the color codification I chose and I cam further look on that if the main approach is a good one. I think that most likely the indexes are build wrong. To build them I have a file with a number between 0 and 190 corresponding to the class for each index. So my index building so far was just read index then index / 190 for each vertex to get a number in [0..1]

**EDIT2**
So I took your advice, did the index + 0.5 / 190 to generate my indexes. I'm printing the length and values of the indice array. It's 60000 and all are numbers between 0 and 1 , mostly between 0.3 and 0.95. But still all my vertices are of the same color. So the only thing I haven't checked is the 1D Texture generation. Maybe here is where I got it wrong:

```
    i = 0
    while i < 30:
        textureArray.append([1,0,0])
        i = i + 1
    while i < 60:
        textureArray.append([1,1,0])
        i = i + 1
    while i < 90:
        textureArray.append([1,1,1])
        i = i + 1
    while i < 120:
        textureArray.append([0,1,1])
        i = i + 1
    while i < 150:
        textureArray.append([0,0,1])
        i = i + 1
    while i < 190:
        i = i + 1 
        textureArray.append([0,0,0])
```

This is how I generate my texture array. This will not be the actual solution but for testing reasons. So my texture should be 1/6 red - 1/6 ... . The texture generation as above:

```
    self.texture = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, self.texture)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGB, 190, 0, GL_RGB , GL_FLOAT, textureArray)
```

Is this texture generating correct ? Because even though my indices range is like I mentioned before, all my vertices have the color of the very first color from the texture. Funny thing is that if I "omit" the glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferTextureIndex) form the drawing and let the normals take the place of the texture indices I do get some different colors, but textureIndexes seem to all point to the very first color from my texture. I've uploaded two sample files with the actual values of textureIndices and normals. No ideea why the first one doesn't work but the second seems to work(can't really verify if they are the correct colors but at least they are different).
http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/315895/textureIndices-txt.html
http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/315894/normalsTest-txt.html

**EDIT3**

So now my indices seems to work. Here is a sample image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvlV3.png

However the odd part is that as you can see the borders are not defined properly. Could this be influenced in any way by some of the parameters I pass to the texture or should I triple check my textureIndex creation ?

Comment: By the way, it should be `i < 190` instead of `191`.

Comment: Thanks, edited. Is there any way to calculate which index should point to what color ? I mean something like: 0 - 29 = red so 0.5 / 190 - 29.5 / 190 = [2.631e-3, 0.1552 ] ? Is this correct ? If so how many decimals are considered ?

Comment: Remember that the computer doesn't know decimals. The precision of the texCoords should be sufficient. You also got nearest filtering, so it isn't that important to exactly hit the texel center.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it working almost perfectly. There is still one issue that I can't get around. Will update post shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. At the moment you use your normals as texture coordinates, because `self.bufferNormals` was bound when calling `glTexCoordPointer`. 1D textures aren't just per vertex colors. they are accessed by per-vertex texture coordinates, like 2D textures, otherwise they would be a useless substitute for per-vertex colors. Read some introductory material on OpenGL texturing or texturing in general if you don't uderstand that.
2. As said above, definitely not.

**EDIT:** According to you newest question (the one with the screenshot), keep in mind, that when the vertices of a single triangle have different texture coordinates (in your case they would belong to different classes, which I suppose shouldn't happen), the texCoords are interpolated accross the triangle and then used to get the texture color. So you have to make sure all vertices of a triangle have the same texCoord if you don't want this to happen (which I suppose). So you have to duplicate vertices along the "material class" borders. Perhaps you could get a quick and dirty solution by just setting glShadeModel(GL_FLAT), but that would also flatten lighting and it is not determined to which class a border triangle belongs then.

Comment: Well it didn't seem right to me either :D. But I still don't understand why I do get only black,red,blue and green points just like I defined in my texture. My normals are really fuzzy data like x.xxx x.xxx x.xxx so I should be getting all kinds of colors shouldn't I ?

Comment: Oh I think I understand what I was misunderstanding. So in my code I defined a texture having black,red,blue and green. Now to know what color is assigned to each point I need to define an coordinate in my texture for each vertex right ? But if so, shouldn't these coordinates in my case be 0=black, 1=blue, 2=green, 3=red ? Why does it work with x.xxx values it takes from self.bufferNormals?

Comment: @Bogdan No, the texture coordinates should be between 0 (black) and 1 (red), but it depends also on the wrapping mode (`GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S`) as it is `GL_REAPEAT` in your case, texCoord 0 is actually the same as 1, 2, ..., they are just taken modulo 1 (therefore only the fraction part matters). Remember 1D textures exactly behave like 2D textures, just 1 dimension less to take care of.

Comment: But you're right, the behaviour of your normals being treated as texture coordinates (between -1 and 1) should with your current filtering `GL_LINEAR` really result in quite blended colors. But I don't know what happens if your texture coordinate array is much smaller (only 4 vertices) than the number of vertices you draw. This should result in an error or at least undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hey, I changes my previous solution. Am I on the right track ?

Comment: @Bogdan Now you're on the right way. `GL_NEAREST` is a good idea for what you are gonna do, but to really be sure about the color, you should compute the texCoord as `((float)index+0.5)/190` assuming `index` goes from 0 to 189, as GL samples the texels at the texel center (therefore the half-texel shift). It could be that the simple `index/190` is sufficient, but I'm not sure if you get precision problems and miss the last color or something similar, so the half-texel shift is the secrue way.

Comment: Did you remember that if your `vertices` array contains 180000 floats, you only render 60000 vertices, so your `textureIndexes` array only has to contain 60000 floats? It's just that I remember these numbers from your last question and want to get sure.

Comment: Hey thanks for the input. Sorry for repost but wasn't sure I explained myself well here.

Comment: Added the texture generation code and some values of textureIndexes and normals.

Comment: But let`s say I have a triangle with vertices (0, 1, 0) -> color green; (0, 0, 0) -> color green; (1, 0, 0) -> color red. Shouldn't the interpolation using GL_NEAREST keep the line between the green points green, most of the triangle green, and then as we approach the red vertice, make the triangle red?

Comment: @Bogdan The nearest filtering applies to the values read from the texture. So the textures colors are not interpolated. It does not apply to the texture coordinates (indices), as they are not indices, but dynamic coordinates. Say you have two vertices, index 2,green and index 4,red. Then the pixels between those vertices will have values between 2 and 4, so the mid between the two vertices will be colored by the color corresponding to index 3, whatever color that is. The indices are interpolated, not the colors.