# glTexCoordPointer seems to have no effect

Tags: opengl, pyopengl

I'm still trying to get a grasp of using textures and now I'm trying to use glTexCoordPointer in order to give each vertex a color specific to it's class. I've made some checks and here is the situation:

```
    self.bufferVertices = glGenBuffersARB(1)
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferVertices)
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, ADT.arrayByteCount(vertices), ADT.voidDataPointer(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB)
    self.vertices = vertices
    self.bufferNormals = glGenBuffersARB(1)
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferNormals)
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, ADT.arrayByteCount(normals), ADT.voidDataPointer(normals), GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB)
    self.normals = normals
    self.triangles = triangles
    textureIndexes = [] 
    for int in areas:
        textureIndexes.append(float(int)/190.0) 
        print str(int) + " " + str(float(int)/190)
    print str(len(self.vertices)) + str(len(textureIndexes))    
    self.bufferTextureIndex = glGenBuffersARB(1)
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferTextureIndex)
    glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, ADT.arrayByteCount(numpy.array(textureIndexes,dtype=numpy.float32)), ADT.voidDataPointer(numpy.array(textureIndexes,dtype=numpy.float32)), GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB)               
    for color in textureArray:
        print str(color)
    self.texture = glGenTextures(1)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, self.texture)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGB, 190, 0, GL_RGB , GL_FLOAT, textureArray)
```

So I generate my VBO's for vertices, normals, triangles and textureIndexes. Now I wanted to check the value I'm getting for textureIndexes, all are from the interval [0..1] and the length of textureIndexes = length ( vertices ) / 3.

For the texture, I generate a textureArray which is a vector of 190 [x,x,x] rgb values. I've even split it in 6 equal parts. So the first 1/6 entries are one color the next another and so on just to simplify my testing.

Now for the drawing:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)         
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferVertices)
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)          
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferNormals)
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, None)     


    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)
    glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, self.bufferTextureIndex)
    glTexCoordPointer(1, GL_FLOAT, 0, None);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, self.texture)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_1D)
    glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(self.triangles) , GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, ADT.voidDataPointer(self.triangles))
```

But all the points are turning out the same color, corresponding  to the color of the first 1/6 part of my texture. Any input would be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you just reboot your question?

Comment: exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185478/opengl-textures-beginner-question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm surprised it is drawing anything at all.  On the following line there is a mistake:

```
    glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_RGB, 190, 0, GL_RGB , GL_FLOAT, textureArray)
```

The OpenGL spec requires that the size of the texture is a power of two.  If you replace the 190 with a 256 or a 64, you may get better results.

Comment: Not neccessarily. It's only required on older hardware (that doesn't support `ARB_texture_non_power_of_two` extension or OpenGL 2.0). Although the ATI guys seem to see this a bit different ;). But it is worth to give it a try, as Bogdan could use old hardware or a broken ATI card.

Comment: I checked the spec and you are right.  However, I've still had fairly mixed results with non-power of two textures, especially on my ATI laptop (which should in theory support OpenGL 2....)  At any rate it would be easy to check, though it might not be the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the observation. My graphics card does support OpenGL 2.0 so there is no problem. However the application should be able to run on older cards too so that will be a problem.